# Setup different environments in Azure using GitFlow and slots: Best practice

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

We have a web application on Azure and we use development slots.
We already set up a dev slot using the development branch in our GIT and using Continuous Build. And we have a test slot using the master branch and our GIT and using Continuous Build.
This works fine.
We are now ready to move on and setup an acceptance and production environment.
What is the best practice?

We thought of setting up a 5th slot: staging to move from acceptance to production. But how to 'fill' the acceptance slot? It is a clone of test at some time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a GitFlow expert but I think in GitFlow Qa usually occurs on a release or hotfix branch, I believe.  Then once the release has passed qa the release branch is merged back into production and staging is reset to master.   Then when its time to launch a new release the updated master branch on the staging deployment slot is swapped into production.